# Derivative of Inverse Function from AP

Tags: derivatives, inverse

An AP question asks:

The function f(x) = x^5 + 3x - 2 passes through the point (1,2). Let f^-1 denote the inverse of f. Then (f^-1)(2) equals?

The inverse of this function should be y^5 + 3y - 2. But, the book says that (f^-1)'(y) = 1 / f'(x).

Isn't there a discrepancy?

Answer (score 1):

The inverse $y=g(x)$ of the function is (in principle) obtained by solving the equation $y^5+3y-2=x$. (Note that the function $x^5+3x-2$ *has* an inverse, since $x^5+3x-2$ is a strictly increasing function.)
This is somewhat related to what you wrote, but different.

The equation $y^5+3y-2-x=0$ is "impossible" to solve explicitly for $y$ in terms of $x$.   (I am oversimplifying). However, we can find the derivative of the inverse function of $f(x)$  at any point by using the formula you quoted.

Comment: Thank you for your response. If I test out the theorem, with the function f(x)= x^2, then that means f ' (x) = 1/2x. However, if I switch x and y in the first function, I arrive at y= square root of x. The derivative of the square root of x does not equal 1/2x.... Is that not relevant?

Comment: Let's test it on $f(x)=x^2$, two inverse functions, let's take $g(t)=\sqrt{t}$, so $g'(t)=1/(2\sqrt{t})$. At $t=9$ this is 1/6$. And the corresponding $x$ is $3$, and 1/f'(t)=1/(2)(3)$.

Comment: Great, big help. Thanks André.